# Assigning strings to string Array without looping

Tags: java, arrays

I have a requirement, to assign the values in array  structure , collections are to be avoided,

```
testFunction(String userName,String Password,String status)
 {
    String[] array;
    if(password==null)
     {
      array={"username",username_variable,"status",status_variable}
    }
    else
    {
     array={"username",userName,"password",password,"status",status}
   }
}
```

Comment: just add new string[] to your existing code in array={....}.

Comment: You appear to be avoiding using a Map or a custom Object to do this.  Do you really have to use an array?

Comment: -1 I don't know if the month of love is over on SO but have you tried buying a java book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java as arrays are objects, so you have to create an object to initialize the elements of the array.

convert

```
array={"username",username_variable,"status",status_variable}
```

to

```
array=new String[]{"username",username_variable,"status",status_variable}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to initialise an array with values:

```
array = new String[] {"username", username_variable, "status", status_variable};
```

You can read more about arrays in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).